# Seasonal component in daily time series remains after stl?

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality

I'm following the procedure in this post ([Adjusting daily time series data for the seasonal component](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185056/adjusting-daily-time-series-data-for-the-seasonal-component)) on R 3.2.3 (linux).

The de-seasoning process in the above post works fine. But with my data, a  weather time series with 32,000+ observations, the same process leaves behind a noticeable seasonal trend, as shown below.

```
> ZI_Index <- ts(ZI_FINAL$ZI, start = c(1926,1,1), frequency = 365.25)
> ZI_Trends <- stl(ZI_Index, s.window = "periodic")
> plot(ZI_Trends)
```

[image: Trends in original time series]

```
> ZI_Detrend <- ZI_Trends$time.series[,"remainder"]
> monthplot(ZI_Detrend)
```

[image: Monthplot of residuals]

```
> ZI_Detrend_Trends <- stl(ZI_Detrend, s.window = "periodic")
> plot(ZI_Detrend_Trends)
```

[image: Trends in remainder of the original time series]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need some sort of hybrid model incorporating memory as well as dummy variables. You might want to look at [R Time Series Forecasting: Questions regarding my output](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143358/r-time-series-forecasting-questions-regarding-my-output/143421#143421) although weather data is not impacted by holidays/day-of-the week etc.. Previous day's weather is often a good forecaster for today's weather.